# Como ir a una sección especifica desde otra pagina con angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Como puedo ir a una sección en especifico a una pagina, desde de otra pagina con angular-js.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Que haz intentado para realizar la función? Podrias agregar tu codigo a tu pregunta para especificar la respuesta.

Comment: Que estas usando como sistema de navegación entre páginas? ui-router o $routeProvider

Answer (score 1):

Imagina que en la otra página tienes un div como este :

```
<div id="vesAqui"></div>
```

Para ir directamente a esa sección puedes usar la propiedad hash `#`:

```
window.location.replace('/path/donde/quieres/ir#vesAqui');
```